# How to avoid conflicts between pylint and pycodestyle about indentation style

Tags: python, pylint, pep8

I have some python code that I run through `pylint` and that I decided to also run through `pycodestyle`.

To avoid long lines in a with statement, I do the following:

```
with my_context_manager(
    argument1,
    argument2) as something:
    rest_of_my_code
```

But `pycodestyle` tells me that

```
E125 continuation line with same indent as next logical line
```

So I indent this further, as follows:

```
with my_context_manager(
        argument1,
        argument2) as something:
    rest_of_my_code
```

But now `pylint` tells me:

```
Wrong hanging indentation (remove 4 spaces).
```

Is there a better solution that would satisfy both code quality checkers?

---

**Note 1**

The following raises no complaints from either of the two style checkers provided that the lines are not too long (which unfortunately is not always the case):

```
with my_context_manager(argument1,
                        argument2) as something:
    rest_of_my_code
```

**Note 2**

To answer comments, I tried the following:

```
with my_context_manager(
    argument1,
    argument2) as something:
        rest_of_my_code
```

Strangely `pycodestyle` still says `E125 continuation line with same indent as next logical line` about the same line as previously (the one with `argument2`).

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you indent `rest_of_my_code` the other way (i.e. ahead of `argument1` and `argument2`)?

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the check in pylint (in .pylintrc add `bad-continuation` to the `disable` option in the **MESSAGE CONTROL** section of the file).

~/.pylintrc

```
[MESSAGES CONTROL]
disable=bad-continuation,...
```

See the FAQ for more about [message-control](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#message-control) config

Answer (score 3):

I formatted the code the following way ...

```
with my_context_manager(
    argument1,
    argument2
) as something:
    rest_of_my_code
```

... and did not get any complaints from pylint and pycodestyle.